# exclude the welcome page or the webroot (/ only) from the security-constraint

Tags: java, security, struts2

i am struggling with the web.xml configuration 
This is what i have

```
<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list> 

<security-constraint> 
<display-name>Unsecure pages</display-name> 
<web-resource-collection> 
<web-resource-name>Unsecure pages</web-resource-name> 
<url-pattern>/jsp/index.jsp</url-pattern> 
</web-resource-collection> 
</security-constraint> 


<security-constraint> 
<display-name>Secure root resources</display-name> 
<web-resource-collection> 
<web-resource-name>Secure root resources</web-resource-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</web-resource-collection> 
<auth-constraint> 
<role-name>RoleA</role-name> 
</auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint> 


<security-constraint> 
<display-name>Specific secure recourses</display-name> 
<web-resource-collection> 
<web-resource-name>Specific secure recourses</web-resource-name> 
<url-pattern>/home</url-pattern> 
<url-pattern>/search</url-pattern> 
</web-resource-collection> 
<auth-constraint> 
<role-name>RoleA</role-name> 
<role-name>RoleB</role-name> 
</auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint> 

and in the index.jsp i have this 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>TITLE</title> 
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=/mpbo/home"></HEAD> 
</HTML>
```

What i want to achieve is that RoleA is supposed to have full Access to the site and the RoleB should only have access to the home page and the search page 
The home page is default for both RoleA and RoleB

The problem i am having is only with the users within RoleB 
When i as a user with RoleB go the the 
`http://localhost:8080/mpbo/` i am prompted to the login page, i login which works fine and then redirected to the /jsp/index.jsp (welcome-file) which tries to redirect me to the /mpbo/home folder but here i get Access is denied. 
If i browse directly to the /mpbo/home folder after i login it is successfull 
If i browse directly to the /jsp/index.jsp file it will successfully redirect me to the /mpbo/home page

So i believe the problem is that the actuall / has a constraint on it. 
I tried to add a url patter with / only and no constraint and even with RoleA and RoleB but it did not work either.

Any ideas how i can get this to work?